# Can a .html file containing ab BwuDatagrid be imported into another .html file?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I have a mediators-medication-form that contains a BwuDatagrid that works when instantiated directly in its mediators-medication-form.html file.

I then import the mediators-medication-form.html file in mediators_view.html as shown below:

```dart
// mediators_view.html ..

  <core-collapse id="core-collapse">
    <div layout horizontal wrap
      class='sibling-container'>
      <mediators-medication-form
        data-receiver='mediators-medication-form --> mediators-view'>
      </mediators-medication-form>
    </div>
  </core-collapse>
```

When this is done and mediators-view instantiated, only the Grid headers are displayed, none of the rows are seen.
I repeat this exercise with other grids with the same result.

Should this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a styling issue. Can you give the grid a fixed height and try again?
The grid doesn't render with some auto size settings. I haven't figured out this fully myself yet.